# Error in loading data from Talend studio to Mysql

Tags: mysql, talend

I'm trying to load a CSV data into mysql from talend studio and getting the below mentioned error:

Couldn't parse value for column 'RegisterTime' in 'row1', value is '1974-10-22 08:46:40.000'. Details: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unparseable date: "1974-10-22 08:46:40.000"

Field RegisterTime has the data type as 'Date' and format as yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS while defining the schema as metadata in the talend studio.

Am I using an incorrect format? Any help in suggesting the right format would be great.

Comment: What is the version of your mysql server?

Comment: are you sure its that format and you don't have the 'T' in the middle of it? The suggested values are not the ones commonly used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a Date pattern problem even though the one you indicate is the right one. You should make sure this pattern is used in the component itself by going to the component view -> "Edit Schema".

Answer (score 0):

because has millisecond,'RegisterTime' the data type should be 'DATETIME' and length is 3.try again

Comment: Talend Studio does not show 'DateTime' data type. 
I've created a schema in Talend and using this to load the csv into mysql.